# MySQL - Update if all records are equal EXCEPT ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database, each row assigned an `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID. I am trying to only `INSERT` a row when it does not exist already, however currently I am finding using `INSERT IGNORE` that the database adds a new row, I believe because the ID's are equal? How would I get a new row to only be inserted when all columns are equal except for the `ID`?

Comment: create routine to take care of that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a unique index on the rest of the columns:

```
create unique index idx_table_allcols on table(col1, col2, . . . );
```

Then your `insert` statement will check that new values are being inserted.  The `INSERT IGNORE` will not insert the record and will not generate an error.